# unable to send form-data in react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, axios

I was using axios to send form-data in RN but it's not working. Noww tried fetch every feild uploads except images. If i use postman, everything works fine.[image]

here is my code:

```
const postOrder = () => {
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('marca', marca);
    data.append('modeo', modeo);
    data.append('option', option);
    data.append('descripcion', descripcion);
    data.append('images[]', images);
    data.append('userId', '2');
    dispatch(saveOrder(data));
  };
    fetch(`${baseUrl}/save-order`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    },
    body: data,
  })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => {
      // dispatch({type: 'ORDER', payload: response.data});
      console.log('json1', json);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
```

every property/feild is beig uploaded except images. I have tried these methods also

```
data.append('file', {
      uri: images,
      type: 'image/jpeg',
      name: 'images[]',
    });
data.append('file',images,'images[])
```

Comment: can you try by adding `Accept: 'application/json',` inside headers

Comment: yes, i tried.. evrything is being uploaded except images

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', {
      uri: pictureUri,
      type: 'image/jpeg',
      name: 'profile-picture'
})
```

I had the same issue, Adding type: 'image/jpeg', to the file attribute of the formData fixed it.

Comment: i get this in response `"data": {"message": "user id is missing", "status": 401},` even though userId is in data

Comment: Even I have get the same weird issue and adding `type: 'image/jpeg',` fixed my issue

Comment: i used fetch insted of axios and it works except image is still not being uploaded

Comment: @RahmanHaroon can u share whole snippet of image property ?

Answer (score 3):

Axios didn't worked for me but fetch api did. here's my working code:
**Post function**

```
const postOrder = () => {
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('marca', marca);
    data.append('modeo', modeo);
    data.append('option', option);
    data.append('description', description);
    data.append('images[]', {
      uri: images,
      name: 'image.jpg',
      type: 'image/jpeg',
    });
    data.append('userId', state.user.id);
    dispatch(saveOrder(data));
  };
```

**Fetch api**

```
 fetch(`${baseUrl}/save-order`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    },
    body: data,
  })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => {
      console.log('json1', json);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
```

if You want to send multiple file do this

```
images.forEach((item, i) => {
      data.append('images[]', {
        uri: item.path,
        type: item.mime,
        name: item.path.slice(-8, -1) + 'g',
      });
    });
```